# Celery CLI - cannot cancel consumer on particular worker on particular node

Tags: queue, celery, command-line-interface, distributed, broker

Using flower I can cancel or add consumer for particular worker on particular node.

However using CLI, I fail and getting this error:

**Error: No nodes replied within time constraint.**

This is the **command**:

```
$ celery control -d worker1@my_node -b redis://remote_broker:6379 cancel_consumer queue_name
```

gives me after 1-2s timeout

```
>> Error: No nodes replied within time constraint.
```

Looking at the status, I can clearly see, that I can reach my worker/node

```
$ celery status -b redis://remote_broker:6379

 worker1@my_node: OK
 worker2@my_node: OK
 worker3@my_node: OK
 worker4@my_node: OK
 4 nodes online. (Not realy sure why celery says 4 nodes, when there is one node and 4 workers [at least in documentation right side is called node])
```

Any idea why I cant remotely cancel/add consumers to particular workers with CLI?

Comment: The command should be like `celery -A celeryapp control cancel_consumer $queue -d $workername`